# Why is it *de*, not *des*, in *un groupe de personnes bruyantes*?

Tags: grammaire, articles, pluriel

In the following sentence:

> En entrant, je suis tombé sur un groupe **de** personnes bruyantes.

I thought since the *personnes* is plural, the article must be either *les* or *des*. So in any case the article is concatenated with *de*, to become *des* (un group des personnes).

However, the sentence uses *de*, not *des*.

I have learned that some of the expressions that are related to the quantity always use *de*, irrespective of any articles following *de*. These expressions include *beaucoup de*, *un peu de*, or *autant de*.

Is the *un groupe de* in such a group? Otherwise, why does the sentence above not take the article to make it *un groupe des*?

Answer (score 2):

First of all I'll go though the larousse [definition](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/groupe/38423) of "groupe" which is a *name*:

> *[nom masculin]*
>   Ensemble de choses, d'animaux ou de personnes, formant un tout et
>   définis par une caractéristique commune : Groupe ethnique. Le groupe
>   des moyens et le groupe des forts.

Than we'll check the [definition](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/personne/) of « personne » :

> *[nom féminin, pronom indéfini]*
>    Individu en général, être humain.
>    Traduction anglais : person, (pluriel) people

When looking for "un groupe de personnes" in [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/un+groupe+de+personnes.html) we can see some exemples:

> Les fiducies servent à
>   procurer un avantage durable à une autre personne ou à **un groupe de personnes**.
>
> Si vous prévoyez rassembler **un groupe de personnes** à cette occasion,
>   faites-le-nous savoir!
>
> Leur ferme tire son nom d'un mot russe qui signifie **un groupe de
>   personnes** travaillant ensemble vers un but commun.

So in conclusion, in the sentence:

> En entrant, je suis tombé sur **un groupe de personnes** bruyantes.

You should not look at *« de »* like a word alone in the sentence, but rather to entire *« un groupe de personnes »* which will always be written this way *(if we're talking about only one group)* no matter the rest of the sentence.

---

***To go further***

If there are various groups of people, we can say instead:

> En entrant, je suis tombé sur ***des*** groupe**s** de personnes bruyantes.

Comment: This does not answer the question of why 'de' rather than 'des'.

Answer (score -3):

- 'groupe' is a noun which can be used by itself, unlike 'un peu de', etc. which are set adverbial phrases.
- 'un groupe' *can* be followed by 'des', for instance "le groupe des huit" (the G8). In a sense (or accurately, I am not sure) 'des' is the definite version ('de' + 'les') against the indefinite 'de': "un groupe de huit" would be any eight (countries in this case), rather than '*the* 8'.

Comment: *"un groupe des gens bruyants que j'avais vus la veille"* is completely incorrect in french

Comment: _Quid_ de https://www.google.com/search?q="groupe+des" ?